# Kinesis Streaming Example Not Working in Cluster Mode on EMR (EMR 4.3, Spark 1.6)

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-emr, amazon-kinesis

I’m trying unsuccessfully to run a version of the Kinesis Streaming word-count example on EMR 4.3 in cluster mode. Specifically, no messages are being read from Kinesis, even though I can access the stream's metadata.

This same code does run in client mode on an identical EMR cluster (i.e. with "local[*]"), but when I try to do it in cluster mode the 1st job of the kinesis receiver is stuck:
[image: spark ui jobs]

And I see nothing in the  streaming page of the Spark UI:
[image: spark ui streaming]

Initially I thought this was a matter of resources/ number of threads, but based on the configuration and what I see in the YARN and Spark UIs, this doesn't seem to be the case (see all relevant configurations below).

**I'm looking for any pointers to why the application cannot read from Kinesis, or for suggested changes in configuration or setup to make this work in cluster mode.**

---

*Configuration and setup details*

The relevant Kinesis stream has a single Shard.

I use the following configuration in the EMR cluster setting:

```
[{"classification":"capacity-scheduler",

"properties":{"yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator":"org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator"}},

{"classification":"spark","properties":{"maximizeResourceAllocation":"true"}},

{"classification":"spark-defaults","properties":{

"spark.executor.instances":"0",
"spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled":"true"}}]
```

And this is how my environment setting look like in the spark ui:
 [image: saprkui env]

The code that I’m trying to run :

```
 val appName =  "ks_"+DateTime.now().toString(formatter);
 val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName)


val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf);
val batchIntervalInSec = 5
val batchInterval = Seconds(batchIntervalInSec)     

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, batchInterval)
ssc.checkpoint("/checkpoint")
 val kinesisClient = new AmazonKinesisClient(credentials)
kinesisClient.setEndpoint(endpointUrl)
val numShards = kinesisClient.describeStream(streamName).getStreamDescription().getShards().size

val numStreams = numShards

val kinesisCheckpointInterval = Seconds(batchIntervalInSec-1) 
val regionName = RegionUtils.getRegionByEndpoint(endpointUrl).getName()


 val kinesisStreams = (0 until numStreams).map { i =>
  KinesisUtils.createStream(ssc, appName, streamName, endpointUrl, regionName,
    InitialPositionInStream.LATEST, kinesisCheckpointInterval, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
}

val unionStreams = ssc.union(kinesisStreams)

val words = unionStreams.flatMap(byteArray => new String(byteArray).split(" "))


val wordCounts = words.map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)

wordCounts.print()
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination();
```

And this is the spark command that I run:

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster 
--class com.komoona.spark.kmn_spark_scala.KinesisStream 
--master yarn --conf spark.executor.cores=4 
--conf spark.executor.instances=2 
--conf spark.streaming.blockInterval=1000ms 
 --jars /home/hadoop/lib/spark-streaming-kinesis-asl-assembly_2.10-1.6.0.jar,/home/hadoop/lib/amazon-kinesis-client-1.6.1.jar, 
test_app_full.jar
```

EDIT: 
I noticed that in spite having 2 executors configured (as specified in the command line), only one executor and the driver are shown running in the spark UI:
[image: executors]

Could this be the source to the issue? Any ideas what can cause this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with aggregated kinesis streams with Spark + Kinesis + EMR (multiple versions tested)...  It turns out that even though the Kinesis library is built explicitly with `protobuf-java-2.6.1` (a requirement due to KCL dependancies), EMR clusters are configured in such a way that it still uses `protobuf-java-2.5.0` in practice.

I haven't been able to look close enough to figure out WHY this is happening, but my quick and dirty solution was to delete `/usr/lib/spark/jars/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar` and replace with my own `protobuf-java-2.6.1` in the same location (on master node).  I keep a version in s3 and have a bootstrap action to `aws s3 cp` the `2.6.1` jar down to the correct location in `/usr/lib/spark/jars`, then add the following to your spark-submit (replacing scala and spark versions where appropriate):

`--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.11:2.1.0,\
com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-2.6.1`

Someone more smarter than me might find a more correct solution than this, but I've not yet seen any obvious side effects from removing `protobuf-java-2.5.0`, though that doesn't mean they don't exist.

You can check if this is the same issue you're having by running (on your spark master) with `--master local[*]` instead of `--master yarn` and look for the following in the logs:

> 17/01/31 19:24:13 ERROR Worker: Worker.run caught exception, sleeping for 1000 milli seconds!
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList.getUnmodifiableView()Lcom/google/protobuf/LazyStringList;

TL;DR -

Replace `protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar` with `protobuf-java-2.6.1.jar` in `/usr/lib/spark/jars/` on spark master

Add (replacing scala and spark versions)

`--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.11:2.1.0,\
com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-2.6.1`

 to your spark-submit command line

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Did you get a chance to look-

> [Spark not able to fetch events from Amazon Kinesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35567440/spark-not-able-to-fetch-events-from-amazon-kinesis)

TL;DR

> There are 2 versions of the foreachRDD available
>
> ```
> unionStreams.foreachRDD
> unionStreams.foreachRDD ((rdd:RDD[Array[Byte]], time: Time)
> ```
>
> For some reason the first one is not able to get me the results but
>   changing to the second one fetches me the results as expected. Yet to
>   explore the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You have 0 spark executors in your config - I believe you must increase that. Also, look in the logs for any errors.

Comment: I saw now that you are specifying the number of executors as an argument in the command line, so ignore that part of my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days of headache, i went over my kinesis configuration again and changed the aggregation mode to off, it solved the whole thing.
kinesis with aggregation mode on worked for me locally,
but not in emr in cluster mode

Comment: How did you change the aggregation mode?

Comment: if you are using logstash (as we did) you can change it in the logstach configuration, bassically this can solve this issue :https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14421. but after a few month of working with spark and kinesis on major scale (100gb per hour) my recomandtion is to stay away from kinesis, it worked in small scale, but once you start loading it with many log producers we had many issues with delayed arrival time of logs and many logs arrive more than once

Comment: Thankyou for the heads up about Kinesis. I couldn't find any docs though on any configuration option to change this aggregation mode. Do you have a link to something like that?

I ended up rolling back to Spark 1.4.1 where it worked, but only gave me the actual payloads but no metadata.