# Kinesis Stream with Empty Records in Google Dataproc with Spark 1.6.1 Hadoop 2.7.2

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop2, amazon-kinesis, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to connect to Amazon Kinesis Stream from Google Dataproc but am only getting Empty RDDs.

```
Command: spark-submit  --verbose --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.10:1.6.2 demo_kinesis_streaming.py --awsAccessKeyId XXXXX        --awsSecretKey XXXX
```

Detailed Log: https://gist.github.com/sshrestha-datalicious/e3fc8ebb4916f27735a97e9fcc42136c

**More Details**
Spark 1.6.1
Hadoop 2.7.2
Assembly Used: /usr/lib/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.7.2.jar

Surprisingly that works when I download and use the assembly containing SPARK 1.6.1 with Hadoop 2.6.0  with the following command.

```
Command: SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6 spark-submit  --verbose --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.10:1.6.2 demo_kinesis_streaming.py --awsAccessKeyId XXXXX        --awsSecretKey XXXX
```

I am not sure if there is any version conflict between the two hadoop versions and Kinesis ASL or it has to do with custom settings with Google Dataproc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Suren

Comment: Could you also provide the contents of `demo_kinesis_streaming.py`? Looking at your logs, I see: `spark.submit.deployMode -> client
spark.master -> local[*]` which implies that for some reason your spark-submit isn't using the cluster's actual Spark settings (assuming you ran that spark-submit on the Dataproc cluster); maybe something is overriding to set spark.master to be local?

Comment: From this seemingly [related SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26941844/apache-spark-kinesis-sample-not-working) and this [AWS forum question](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=705666] it seems empty may be related to not having enough executors running to both receive and process the data. If somehow you're getting local[2] then it makes sense that may not be able to process your stream. Furthermore, on a dataproc cluster you'll want to make sure you have a large enough cluster to hold enough executors as well.

Comment: Hi @DennisHuo, Thanks for your response. Here is the link to the [demo_kinesis_streaming.py](https://gist.github.com/sshrestha-datalicious/c5efcdcb014da69d361768646f898788).

Regarding your comment about `client spark.master` being `local[*]`, I had tested this script by logging (`ssh`) into Dataproc master node and did a `spark-submit`.

Thanks
Suren

Comment: In case my comments below get buried, the problematic old aws-java-sdk version comes from [Hadoop core itself](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/branch-2.7.2/hadoop-project/pom.xml#L650), which makes it difficult to shade in the distro without potentially breaking other users who inadvertently depend on the leaky classpaths. We can backport Hadoop's version bump of the AWS SDK from [Hadoop 2.8](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/commit/f7b0f292e722fa819900f455a070be1d7bf97072) into Dataproc 1.1 but in general it's still best to always shade your aws-java-sdk dependencies yourself.

Comment: The SDK's presence in the hadoop-mapreduce path basically means you'd potentially run into classpath collision issues across all different Hadoop distros including outside of Dataproc, even if the versions are made to match in the short term.

Answer (score 2):

Our team was in a similar situation and we managed to solve it:

We are running on the same environment:

- DataProc Image Version 1 with Spark 1.6.1 with Hadoop 2.7
- A simple SparkStream Kinesis Script that boils down to this:

  ```
  # Run the script as
  # spark-submit  \
  #    --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.10:1.6.1\
  #    demo_kinesis_streaming.py\
  #    --awsAccessKeyId FOO\
  #    --awsSecretKey BAR\
  #    ... 

  import argparse

  from pyspark import SparkContext
  from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
  from pyspark.storagelevel import StorageLevel

  from pyspark.streaming.kinesis import KinesisUtils, InitialPositionInStream

  ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  ap.add_argument('--awsAccessKeyId', required=True)
  ap.add_argument('--awsSecretKey', required=True)
  ap.add_argument('--stream_name')
  ap.add_argument('--region')
  ap.add_argument('--app_name')
  ap = ap.parse_args()

  kinesis_application_name = ap.app_name
  kinesis_stream_name = ap.stream_name
  kinesis_region = ap.region
  kinesis_endpoint_url = 'https://kinesis.{}.amazonaws.com'.format(ap.region)

  spark_context = SparkContext(appName=kinesis_application_name)
  streamingContext = StreamingContext(spark_context, 60)

  kinesisStream = KinesisUtils.createStream(
      ssc=streamingContext,
      kinesisAppName=kinesis_application_name,
      streamName=kinesis_stream_name,
      endpointUrl=kinesis_endpoint_url,
      regionName=kinesis_region,
      initialPositionInStream=InitialPositionInStream.TRIM_HORIZON,
      checkpointInterval=60,
      storageLevel=StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2,
      awsAccessKeyId=ap.awsAccessKeyId,
      awsSecretKey=ap.awsSecretKey
  )

  kinesisStream.pprint()

  streamingContext.start()
  streamingContext.awaitTermination()
  ```
- The code had been tested **working** on AWS EMR and on local environment using the same Spark 1.6.1 with Hadoop 2.7 setup.
- The script is returning empty RDDs *without* printing any error while there **is** data in the Kinesis stream on DataProc.
- We've tested it on DataProc with the following envs, and **none** of them worked.

  1. Submit job via `gcloud` command;
  2. `ssh` into Cluster Master Node and run in `yarn` client mode;
  3. `ssh` into Cluster Master Node and run as `local[*]`.

---

Upon enabling verbose logging by updating `/etc/spark/conf/log4.properties` with the following value:

```
    log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, console
    log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
    log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c: %m%n
    log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty=ERROR
    log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=ERROR
    log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=DEBUG
    log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=DEBUG
    log4j.logger.org.apache.spark=DEBUG 
    log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation=DEBUG
    log4j.logger.org.spark-project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler=DEBUG
    log4j.logger.org.apache=DEBUG
    log4j.logger.com.amazonaws=DEBUG
```

---

We've notice something weird in the log(Note that `spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.10:1.6.1` uses `aws-sdk-java/1.9.37` as dependence while somehow `aws-sdk-java/1.7.4` was used [suggested by user-agent]):

```
    16/07/10 06:30:16 DEBUG com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.ShardConsumer: PROCESS task encountered execution exception:
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.GetRecordsResult.getMillisBehindLatest()Ljava/lang/Long;
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.ShardConsumer.checkAndSubmitNextTask(ShardConsumer.java:137)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.ShardConsumer.consumeShard(ShardConsumer.java:126)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker.run(Worker.java:334)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisReceiver$$anon$1.run(KinesisReceiver.scala:174)

    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.GetRecordsResult.getMillisBehindLatest()Ljava/lang/Long;
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.ProcessTask.call(ProcessTask.java:119)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.call(MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.java:48)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.call(MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.java:23)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    content-length:282
    content-type:application/x-amz-json-1.1
    host:kinesis.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
    user-agent:SparkDemo,amazon-kinesis-client-library-java-1.4.0, aws-sdk-java/1.7.4 Linux/3.16.0-4-amd64 OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.91-b14/1.8.0_91
    x-amz-date:20160710T063016Z
    x-amz-target:Kinesis_20131202.GetRecords
```

---

<s>It appears that DataProc had build its own Spark with a much older AWS SDK as dependencies and it will blow up when used in conjunction with codes that requires much newer version of AWS SDK although we are not sure exactly which module had cause this error.</s>

**Update:**
Base on @DennisHuo's comment, this behaviour is caused by Hadoop's leaky classpath:
https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/branch-2.7.2/hadoop-project/pom.xml#L650

To make things worst, the AWS KCL 1.4.0 (used by Spark 1.6.1) [will suppress any runtime error silently](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client/blob/4dfc17d04a5b6d740fa6c61186f41da0a93d1177/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/kinesis/clientlibrary/lib/worker/ShardConsumer.java#L160-L163) instead of throwing `RuntimeException` and causing a lot of headache while debugging.

---

Eventually Our solution was to build our `org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.10:1.6.1` with all of its `com.amazonaws.*` shaded.

Building the JAR with the following pom (update `spark/extra/kinesis-asl/pom.xml`) and shit the new JAR with `--jars` flag in `spark-submit`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-parent_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
    <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>

  <!-- Kinesis integration is not included by default due to ASL-licensed code. -->
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.10</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>Spark Kinesis Integration</name>

  <properties>
    <sbt.project.name>streaming-kinesis-asl</sbt.project.name>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>amazon-kinesis-client</artifactId>
      <version>${aws.kinesis.client.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>amazon-kinesis-producer</artifactId>
      <version>${aws.kinesis.producer.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scalacheck</groupId>
      <artifactId>scalacheck_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-test-tags_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <outputDirectory>target/scala-${scala.binary.version}/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>target/scala-${scala.binary.version}/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <shadedArtifactAttached>false</shadedArtifactAttached>

            <artifactSet>
              <includes>
                <!-- At a minimum we must include this to force effective pom generation -->
                <include>org.spark-project.spark:unused</include>
                <include>com.amazonaws:*</include>
              </includes>
            </artifactSet>

            <relocations>
              <relocation>
                <pattern>com.amazonaws</pattern>
                <shadedPattern>foo.bar.YO.com.amazonaws</shadedPattern>
                <includes>
                  <include>com.amazonaws.**</include>
                </includes>
              </relocation>
            </relocations>

          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: @DennisHuo, Would you please confirm that DataProc is shipping a much older version of `aws-java-sdk`? If so, is there any chance to shade it by default? Thanks.

Comment: I just double checked, Dataproc-specific code definitely doesn't import any older `aws-java-sdk` dependencies. It comes from the [hadoop-mapreduce build itself](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/branch-2.7.2/hadoop-project/pom.xml#L650), apparently mostly for [S3A](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/c58a59f7081d55dd2108545ebf9ee48cf43ca944/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3a/S3AOutputStream.java). It would unfortunately be somewhat risky to shade it in core Hadoop, since other people will have come to depend on the leaky-classpath behavior.

Comment: Based on the hadoop-project commit [which updated the aws-java-sdk version](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/commit/f7b0f292e722fa819900f455a070be1d7bf97072), there are some minor changes in the S3 interface that had to be made. However, checking the javadoc it does appear the newer versions are at least backwards-compatible even though the [method is deprecated](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectMetadata.html#getServerSideEncryption--).

Comment: We can at least make sure to backport the [patch from Hadoop 2.8](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/commit/f7b0f292e722fa819900f455a070be1d7bf97072) in our upcoming Dataproc 1.1 version, but incrementing a minor version of a lib dependency in a Dataproc 1.0.x subminor release may be too risky. I'd say as long as Hadoop core imports the AWS java SDK unshaded itself, the safest thing to do is to shade any AWS libraries in your own builds.

Comment: @DennisHuo Thanks for looking into this. Just out of curious, I wonder if you would know why it would work without shading in spark-dist builds? Would it because they does not rely on external hadoop dependencies? Thanks.

Comment: I checked the prebuilt spark and indeed it doesn't pull in any of the `S3AFileSystem` and thus it doesn't include the AWS SDK jars; this also means that even though prebuilt Spark tarballs self-bundle the typical `hadoop-common` libraries necessary to access HDFS proper, it lacks the extra `hadoop-tools` artifacts that *do* come in a standard Hadoop tarball, and thus can't access these other integration libraries in [hadoop-tools](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/tree/branch-2.6.0/hadoop-tools).

Comment: The specific artifactId which causes the problems in this post is [hadoop-aws](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/branch-2.6.0/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/pom.xml); normal Hadoop distributions like Hortonworks, Cloudera, etc., will indeed contain these just like Dataproc and EMR, while self-contained Spark assemblies that aren't part of a full Hadoop distribution may not have them.

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation. Much appreciated.